# Creating output for npm csvtojson

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I'm trying to read in my .CSV file and output a .json file using npm's [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson)

I am using the following code:

```
//Converter Class 
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var converter = new Converter({});
var fs = require("fs");

//end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished 
converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonArray) {
    console.log(jsonArray); //here is your result jsonarray 
});

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
    .pipe(csv2json({
        // Defaults to comma. 
        separator: '|'
    }))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('dataOut.json'));
```

However, I'm running into the error "*csv2json is not defined*"

Does anyone know why I'm running into this error, despite including "csvtojson" on the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cvs2json` is *not* defined anywhere in your code.  The cannocial example for `cvs2json` (from https://github.com/julien-f/csv2json) is:

```
var csv2json = require('csv2json');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv2json({
    // Defaults to comma.
    separator: ';'
  }))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data.json'));
```

So the simple answer is to change your first line to `var csv2json = require('csv2json');`.  However, this would cause an error in your attempt to have the `end_parse` event fire.  To listen to that event, use the Node Stream eventing:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
    .pipe(csv2json({
        // Defaults to comma. 
        separator: '|'
    }));
stream.on('end', function (jsonArray) {
    console.log(jsonArray); //here is your result jsonarray 
});
stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('dataOut.json'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implement hope it helps.

```
let csv2Json = require('convert-csv-to-json');

let fileInputName = 'stores.csv';
let fileOutputName = 'stores.json';

csv2Json.fieldDelimiter(',').generateJsonFileFromCsv(fileInputName, 
fileOutputName);

//To display json you created on terminal. 
let json = csv2Json.getJsonFromCsv("stores.csv");
   for(let i=0; i<json.length;i++){
   console.log(json[i]);
}
```

Once you run the file, it is going to create the json file, if it is exists it is going to overwrite it.